# PHP Alternative to using a query within a loop 5

Tags: php, mysql, json

I was told that it is a bad practice to use a query (select) within a loop because it slows down server performance.

I have an `JSONObject` such as

```
{"937815200":"contact_name1",
"916611810":"contact_name2",
"937233346":"contact_name3",
"935719080":"contact_name4"}
```

The JSON I'm using does not have a constant size, so sometimes it can contain as many as indexes.

Right now, what I'm doing is (this is not all of the code, but the basic idea)

1. For loop
2. query the server and select all people's phones who in "users table"
3. Print the names out

Output will look like this:

```
{contact_name1:true,
contact_name2:true,
contact_name3:fasle,
contact_name4:false
```

I know that's a really inefficient method because it could be a lot of queries as the table gets larger later on.

So my question is, is there a better, more efficient way to SELECT information based on the stuff inside an JSONObject that can be whatever size?

First of all, I get information from the client here:

```
  $json = $_POST["contacts_json"];
        $tempArray = array();
        $json_a = json_decode($json);
        foreach ($json_a as $key => $val) {
            $item = getFriends($key);
             if (!$item) {
                 // do nothing
             } else {
                 array_push($tempArray, ($item));
             }
        }
        echo json_encode(($tempArray));
```

And this is an SELECT area :

```
function getFriends($phone)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`phone` LIKE '%$phone%' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["getFriends"]["real_name"] = $result["real_name"];
        $response["getFriends"]["user_unique_id"] = $result["status"];
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: You might consider using the `WHERE users.phone IN(111,2222,333)`   Syntax. Assuming the phone numbers are complete phone numbers. I see you are using `LIKE` in your current query rather than `=` so maybe they are not complete phone numbers

Comment: "So my question is, is there a better, more efficient way to SELECT information based on the stuff inside an JSONObject that can be whatever size?" if you change the JSON object it should be possible to parse the phone numbers in MySQL with something like `$.[*].phone_number` and use them as delivered LEFT JOIN table within MySQL directly. Meaning no more loops.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You've completely understood. They are part of the phone number

Comment: @RaymondNijland Maybe you're right. So please show me a sample code.

Comment: it's not that easy mine last comment was giving you a wrong view. You need to simulate SQL standard `JSON_TABLE` which MySQL 8.0 supports. Or your MySQL server needs to support `JSON_EXTRACT`, `JSON_KEYS` and `JSON_LENGTH`  functions  which is available from MySQL version 5.7+ to make it possible to write SQL that can simulate `JSON_TABLE`.. Besides you also need to create a SQL number generator (records with numbers in sequence)  and merge it with the `JSON_EXTRACT`, `JSON_KEYS` and `JSON_LENGTH` functions so it will be a complex SQL query